# Javascript Form Calculator with both onInput and onChange pointing to same function. Need to store onChange

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

#### Background

I have a form I'm building that will function as a price calculator. I've been messing with it for too long, and now I'm stuck.

Basically, when a user inputs two (actually three) variables, it will produce three different outputs.

The three inputs:

- Tickets Sold
- Ticket Cost
- Who pays the fee?

The three outputs:

- They Pay
- You Pay
- You Get Paid (net revenue)

The formula is fairly straightforward.

> (Tickets Sold) x (Ticket Cost) = BasePrice (or call it gross revenue if you like)
>
> (Number of tickets sold x $1) + (BasePrice/100) = Fee (this is essentially $1 for each ticket + 1% of BasePrice)

Based on the "who pays the fee" variable, you get the three outputs. It's either they pay baseprice plus fee, or they pay the baseprice and you pay the fee. Then the revenue is simply what they pay minus what you pay, less the fee, which goes to a third party regardless.

#### Example:

> 1 ticket sold at $10 would produce two potential outputs.
>
> Output 1 – With "they pay" selected: $11.10 they pay, $0 you pay, and $10 revenue.
>
> Output 2 – With "cover the fees" selected: $10 they pay, $1.10 you pay, and $8.90 revenue.

Make sense?

#### Question:

I have this working to a point. **My outputs are working as intended. But if you change the first two variables, it defaults back to the main "attendee pays" setting. I want it to keep the chosen radio input and show the correct outputs no matter which one of the three variables changes.** I'm sure I'm just missing some syntax somewhere, but because of all the variables, I can't find it.

Code is below, and here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36ce05ft/4/).

Thank you in advance!

```
        <div class="pricing-table">
            <form id="pricingform" oninput="calculateTotal()">

                <div class="price-row grid">
                    <div class="col-1-2">
                        Tickets Sold: <input type="text" name="ticketssold" id="ticketssold"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-2">
                        Ticket Price: <input type="text" name="ticketprice" id="ticketprice">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price-row">
                    <div class="col-full">
                        Fees:
                        <input type="radio" name="fees" value="PassOn" onchange="calculateTotal(this.value)" checked> <label>Pass Onto Attendee</label> <input type="radio" name="fees" value="CoverFees" onchange="calculateTotal(this.value)"> <label>Cover the Fees</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price-row grid">
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Attendees Pay:</label><br /> <output id="attendees" name="attendees" for="a b">$0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Estimated Cost:</label><br /> <output style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="percent" me="percent"></output><output id="cost" name="cost">$0</output>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Estimated Revenue:</label><br /> <output id="revenue" name="revenue">$0</output>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>   

        <script>
            function getBasePrice() {
                    var baseprice = parseInt(ticketssold.value)*parseFloat(ticketprice.value);
                    return baseprice;
                }

            function getFees() {
                    var percent = parseFloat(ticketssold.value*ticketprice.value/100);
                    var dollar = parseInt(ticketssold.value);
                    var fees = +percent + +dollar;
                    return fees;
                }

            function calculateTotal(answer) {                

                    var baseprice = getBasePrice();         
                    var fees = getFees();             

                    if (answer == "CoverFees") {
                            var attendeespay = +baseprice;
                            var venuepays = +fees;
                            var revenuetotal = +baseprice - +fees;
                        } else {
                            var attendeespay = +baseprice + +fees;
                            var venuepays = 0.00;
                            var revenuetotal = +baseprice;
                        }

                    revenue.value = "$"+revenuetotal.toFixed(2);
                    attendees.value = "$"+attendeespay.toFixed(2);
                    cost.value = "$"+venuepays.toFixed(2); 
                };


        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because oninput calls calculateTotal without parameters

```
<form id="pricingform" oninput="calculateTotal()">
```

In JS Added: `var answer = "";`

In HTML changed fees inputs to `<input type="radio" name="fees" value="PassOn" onchange="answer='';calculateTotal()" checked> <label>Pass Onto Attendee</label> <input type="radio" name="fees" value="CoverFees" onchange="answer='CoverFees';calculateTotal()"> <label>Cover the Fees</label>`

```js
var answer = "";
            function getBasePrice() {
                    var baseprice = parseInt(ticketssold.value)*parseFloat(ticketprice.value);
                    return baseprice;
                }

            function getFees() {
                    var percent = parseFloat(ticketssold.value*ticketprice.value/100);
                    var dollar = parseInt(ticketssold.value);
                    var fees = +percent + +dollar;
                    return fees;
                }

            function calculateTotal() {                
console.log(answer)
                    var baseprice = getBasePrice();         
                    var fees = getFees();             

                    if (answer == "CoverFees") {
                            var attendeespay = +baseprice;
                            var venuepays = +fees;
                            var revenuetotal = +baseprice - +fees;
                        } else {
                            var attendeespay = +baseprice + +fees;
                            var venuepays = 0.00;
                            var revenuetotal = +baseprice;
                        }

                    revenue.value = "$"+revenuetotal.toFixed(2);
                    attendees.value = "$"+attendeespay.toFixed(2);
                    cost.value = "$"+venuepays.toFixed(2); 
                };
```

```html
<div class="pricing-table">
            <form id="pricingform" oninput="calculateTotal()">

                <div class="price-row grid">
                    <div class="col-1-2">
                        Tickets Sold: <input type="text" name="ticketssold" id="ticketssold"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-2">
                        Ticket Price: <input type="text" name="ticketprice" id="ticketprice">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price-row">
                    <div class="col-full">
                        Fees:
                        <input type="radio" name="fees" value="PassOn" onchange="answer='';calculateTotal()" checked> <label>Pass Onto Attendee</label> <input type="radio" name="fees" value="CoverFees" onchange="answer='CoverFees';calculateTotal()"> <label>Cover the Fees</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="price-row grid">
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Attendees Pay:</label><br /> <output id="attendees" name="attendees" for="a b">$0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Estimated Cost:</label><br /> <output style="display:none;" type="hidden" id="percent" me="percent"></output><output id="cost" name="cost">$0</output>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-3">
                        <label>Estimated Revenue:</label><br /> <output id="revenue" name="revenue">$0</output>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew I was doing something not quite right. Thanks a ton, that worked!